# Unexpected result from datasciencetoolkit.org API

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-maps, geocoding

I'm trying to reverse geocode a large array of latitude/longitude coordinate pairs. I want to get the country for every coordinate pair.

I'm transforming an array of latitude/longitude pairs `[[ 26.46469, 106.63241 ], ...]` into an array of objects with latitude and longitude keys ([per datasciencetoolkit.org docs](http://www.datasciencetoolkit.org/developerdocs#coordinates2politics)) `[{"latitude":26.46469,"longitude":106.63241}, ...]` and sending the array as JSON in a POST request body to the `/coordinates2politics` endpoint.

I'm getting a 200 response but the response body indicates that every latitude/longitude coordinate pair I sent over was `0, 0`. Response body: `[ { politics: null, location: { latitude: 0, longitude: 0 } }, ...]`.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

I'm running this code in a Node.js (v6.5) repl in my text editor, using the 'request' package installed with npm.

```
const testCoords = [
  [ 26.46469, 106.63241 ],
  [ 48.76367, 21.17633 ],
  [ 38.70066, -77.21163 ]
];

const postData = testCoords.map(([latitude, longitude]) => ({latitude, longitude}));

console.log(postData)

const request = require('request');

const options = {
  uri: 'http://www.datasciencetoolkit.org/coordinates2politics',
  method: 'POST',
  json: postData
};

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  if (error) console.log(error);
  console.log(response.statusMessage, body);
});
```

Comment: You haven't read the documentation very well, because there's no mention of POSTing a json array of objects containing lat/long properties in that documentation at all

Comment: try using testCoords where you have json: postData - i.e. you didn't need the `.map` part of your code at all

Comment: You were absolutely right. I didn't need to map the coordinates to objects. It worked fine when I removed `.map`. I'm still confused by the documentation though. It says... "Coordinates to Politics:
This API takes either a single string representing a comma-separated pair of latitude/longitude coordinates, or a JSON-encoded array of objects containing two keys, one for latitude and one for longitude."